# HTTP streaming from VLC player to AVD using Android VideoView

Tags: java, android, streaming, vlc, android-videoview

I'm trying to streaming a 3gp video on android emulator (v. 2.3.3 - Eclipse IDE). I prepare a stream with VLC media player using HTTP on port 9090 without any transcoding. For testing streaming I open a new instance of VLC and connecting on my local ip (192.168.1.107:9090) I see the video without any problems. Now I try on Android using this code on onCreate(Bundle) method of my Activity class:

```java
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
String uri = "http://192.168.1.107:9090";
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

but when application starts, appears this message: "Impossible to reproduce the video". Here the logcat:

```
D/MediaPlayer(454): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer(454): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(454): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView(454): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

I've tried also with the URI 10.0.2.2:9090 with the same result and 127.0.0.1:9090 with the same message and the error range (1, -111)

Note that the same video works fine if I play it on local:

```java
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo;
```

I use `Windows 7 x64`.

Edit: I've also tried to upload the video on the public folder of my Dropbox with the same error, but using the original [link](http://daily3gp.com/vids/familyguy_has_own_orbit.3gp) it works! Is there a problem with my local network? What does it mean the error (1,x)?

Edit2: I've started a XAMPP session on my local network and I've put the video on a folder. The ip address is something like this:

```
String uri = "http://192.168.1.107:8080/myfolder/myvideo.3gp";
```

and it works, even if this is not properly streaming, but something like active download (as the example on the web in my first edit).

Comment: Does the stream work if you open the URL in desktop Browser? How about Android browser?

Comment: @PeterKnego Google Chrome download a file named "download" without any extension. Android browser also download a file but in download folder I read "failed" under my ip and <Unknown>.

Comment: I would suggest try using a more concrete url http://192.168.1.107:9090/myfile.3gp instead of the naked domain:port. also, try testing it on a real device.

Comment: @yorkw I've tried but the error is the same with different range (1, -1004). Unfortunately I've not an android device.

Comment: Android should also be able to view rtsp: streams and although I have been able to open some test streams on the web from my HTC Desire phone, I have been unable to set up VLC to stream rtsp that the Android media player supports (plays fine in VLC though when connecting to the rtsp stream it creates).

Comment: @Johncl I've used a [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/) to stream the video in RTSP and open it with AVD. Since this solution need a Mac OS I've not post an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your local web server delivers the video with the correct `Content-Type` (or mime type) set in the HTTP response header?

Your original link uses `Content-Type: video/3gpp`

For VLC you can specify the content or mime type on the options page. According to the [documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html) you have to edit the option string and add

```
:mime=video/3gpp
```

Comment: I don't know in which way VLC sends the stream in HTTP. I simply use something like [this](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Easy_Streaming_Newer_Versions) to stream the video.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand _where_ I have to specify the mime type.

Comment: Open the link you have posted in your first comment and scoll down to the "Options" section. There you can see the "generated Stream output string" which has to be modified.

Comment: Ok I've modified the string that in this way become: `:sout=#duplicate{dst=http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:9090/},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep:mime=video/3gp` but the error shown is the same.